# detect Vulnerability OWASP with maven

Tags: java, maven, security, dependencies, owasp

In my project , i want to detect vulnerabilities by using dependency-check-maven plugin: 
so I added this piece of code in the POM.XML

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <failBuildOnCVSS>6</failBuildOnCVSS>
                    <format>ALL</format>
                    <outputDirectory>${dependency.check.report.dir}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

When i executed the command `mvn clean package`

the result : Two files dependency-check-report and dependency-check-vulnerability are generated in the folder target of my projet but their content are like this :

```
Scan Information (show all):
•dependency-check version: 1.2.8

•Report Generated On: déc. 9, 2019 at 14:19:59 GMT+01:00

•Dependencies Scanned: 78

•Vulnerable Dependencies: 0

•Vulnerabilities Found: 0

•Vulnerabilities Suppressed: 0
```

So when i saw the console message , i found the message

```
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\ychakir\master\contraste-server\contraste-war\src\main\webapp]

[INFO] Webapp assembled in [6238 msecs]

[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\ychakir\master\contraste-server\contraste-war\target\contraste-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war

[INFO]
[INFO] --- dependency-check-maven:1.2.8:check (default) @ contraste-war ---

dÚc. 09, 2019 2:22:04 PM org.owasp.dependencycheck.Engine analyzeDependencies

GRAVE: No documents exist`
```

Do you have any idea please let me know ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: First I would strongly recommend to use a most recent version of dependency-check-maven plugin see https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:dependency-check-maven Furthermore the sonar plugin is not the right one...

Comment: Hello @khmarbaise ! when i tried to download  the last version 5.2.4 I encountered this error : [ERROR] Unable to download meta file: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-modified.meta

Comment: Where are you trying to download the dependency-check-maven plugin? Just update your pom file (change version in your pom file) ...the download will be done by Maven automatically...

Answer (score 1):

You could take an alternative approach to running `dependency-check-maven` by directly invoking it with this command, mentioned [here](https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck#maven-plugin):

```
mvn org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:check
```

Of course, with this method the dependency check does not get run as part of your build. But it saves you the effort of adding it into your pom.xml.